# Solving the trigonometric equation $\sin3x=\cos2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I solve the equation $$\sin 3x=\cos 2x$$ for $x$ in the range $[0,\pi]$?

I already have a solution elaborated in the answer below.But is there any way of solving this without using the double and triple angle identities? (The problem arises as homework in a high school mathematics class which hasn't leant the identities yet.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is $\cos(\frac\pi2-3x)=\cos(2x)$. Now, since $\cos A=\cos B\iff \exists k\in\Bbb Z, A-B=2k\pi\lor\exists h\in\Bbb Z, A+B=2h\pi$, this becomes $$\frac\pi2-3x=2k\pi+2x\lor \frac\pi2-3x=2h\pi-2x\\ x=-\frac25\pi k+\frac\pi{10}\lor x=-2h\pi+\frac\pi2$$

Now, the only such angles in $[0,\pi]$ are obtained for $k=0,-1,-2$ or for $h=0$. Therefore the solution is $x\in\left\{\frac\pi{10},\frac\pi2,\frac9{10}\pi\right\}$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is, using the a basic identity; rewrite the equation as 
$$\cos\Bigl(\frac\pi 2- 3x\Bigr)=\cos 2x\iff \frac\pi 2- 3x\equiv\pm 2x\pmod{2\pi}\iff\begin{cases}
5x\equiv \frac\pi2\\\phantom{5}x\equiv\frac\pi 2
\end{cases}\pmod{2\pi} $$
The first equation is equivalent to
$$x\equiv\frac\pi{10}\pmod{\tfrac{2\pi}5}\quad\text{i.e.}\quad x=\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{10},\; k\in\mathbf Z.$$
There remains to sort the solutions which live in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: (+1) Nice, I wouldn't have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [triple angle identity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/triple-angle-identities/#targetText=Triple%20Angle%20Identities,functions%20of%20the%20angle%20itself.&targetText=The%20triple%20angle%20identity%20of,in%20a%20very%20similar%20manner.) for sine and [double angle identity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/double-angle-identities/) for cosine, the equation reduces to
$$3\sin x-4\sin^3x=1-2\sin^2 x.$$
Naturally we substitute $s=\sin x$, then this becomes
the cubic equation
$$4s^3-2s^2-3s+1=0.$$
Now, observe that $s=1$ is a root, so factor that out from the LHS to get
$$(s-1)(4s^2+2s-1)=0.$$
Solving the quadratic, we have $s=\frac14(-1\pm\sqrt5)$. Correspondingly, we obtain the $x$ values:
$$x=\frac\pi2, \arcsin\left(\frac14(-1+\sqrt5)\right), \pi-\arcsin\left(\frac14(-1+\sqrt5)\right)=\frac\pi2,\frac\pi{10},\frac{9\pi}{10}$$

Comment: No, you don't just take the $\arcsin$ of these values, because there is no $x\in [0,\pi]$ such that $\sin x=\frac{-1-\sqrt 5}4$. You take all the solutions in $[0,\pi]$ to the equations $\sin x=\alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i$ ranges over the non-negative roots of that polynomial. Namely, you'll take $\arcsin 1$, $\arcsin\frac{\sqrt 5-1}4$ and $\pi-\arcsin\frac{\sqrt 5-1}4$.

Comment: @Gae.S. You're right, I have edited the answer to reflect that. Thanks for the help!